Latest versions do not contain cassandra.bat
I'm trying to install Cassandra DB from https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html
The latest and the second latest version do not contain in the bin folder the file cassandra.bat but there is a file named cassandra without extensions.
Sorry for the dummy question but how can I open the bins? If I run cassandra on my terminal windows opens a popup to select a program to open cassandra

Thanks for posting your question! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Try running Cassandra from within WSL on Windows.

Over the years, Cassandra has had ongoing problems running on Windows machines particularly with the Java file I/O library being problematic with NTFS.
As a result, we decided to that it was not good for the project that users constantly run into these issues (see the discussion thread on the mailing list) so support for Windows was dropped completely in 2020 (CASSANDRA-16171). This is the reason you can no longer find the startup script for Windows.
I suggest the following alternatives:

Deploy Cassandra on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2)
Deploy Cassandra in Docker
Deploy Cassandra in a Kubernetes cluster with open-source K8ssandra.io

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, Astra DB has a free tier where you can launch a cluster in about 60 seconds with no credit card required. Cheers!
